# possible to rewrite any and all sub directories to root using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to rewrite **any/all** sub directories to point to the same root.

For example `domain.com/` and `domain.com/dir` (`dir` can be any directory) need to go the the same place and even sub domains like `sub.domain.com/dir` need to go to the same place.

It is key that any sub directories and/or sub domains stay intact because the sub domain and sub directory elements will be used to make determination about what the user is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to rewrite any/all sub directories to point to the same root.

Yes you can have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# It is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# It is a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# If request is for other than root then route to /
RewriteRule .+ / [L]
```

**Also make sure to:**

1. Keep same `DocumentRoot` for all sub domains.
2. You shouldn't have any other `.htaccess` in sub directories.